# use a range of colors from the value of RGB value

Tags: php, colors, range

I want to use a range of colors using the value of RGB values

Suppose rbg of black color in ideal condition is rgb(0,0,0) but when  i scan any image.It's color range varies from 0 to 51 like rgb(31,31,31),rgb(49,49,49) etc

what i required to use a  color range for condition

if(r=0 to 51 && g=0 to 51 && b=0 to 51)
condition execute

Another thing all three values ie rgb should have similar value for example:-rgb(0,0,0) rgb(31,31,31)etc
so that combine color resembles black color

Making sense?

Im using PHP

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the RGB color first to HSL, with HSL you can compare Hue, Saturation and Luminance of colors.

Comparing the Hue of two colors, gets all colors that are for example blue(ish). Black and White are a bit special in this case, you could test for extreme Luminance (near 0% or near 100%) for black/white, or low Saturation (near 0%) for grey colors.

Comment: hue=160 sat=0 remain same for black to grey but lum changing there value.

Comment: @AnkurSaxena - I updated the answer, to show the problems with black/grey/white colors, the Hue does not make a difference for this extreme cases.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just to some comparisons of the values to determine if they fall in the black spectrum of RGB? Such as:

```
$rgb = array("R" => 0, "G" => 0, "B" => 0);
if($rgb->R >= 0 && $rgb->R <= 51 && $rgb->G >= 0 && $rgb->G <= 51 && $rgb->B >= 0 && $rgb->B <= 51) {
    // RGB value is in black spectrum
}
```

Comment: $rgb = array("R" => 0, "G" => 0, "B" => 0);//why you are using array here please explain.